# Simplify series of elif statements in Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a tic-tac-toe ai program with a board formatted like this:

```
board = [['X','O','X'],[' ','O',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]
```

I have a series of `elif` statements like this, which checks if a side is empty, and if so return the board position of that side:

```
if board[1][0] == ' ':
    return 1, 0
elif board[1][2] == ' ':
    return 1, 2
elif board[0][1] == ' ':
    return 0, 1
else:
    return 2, 1
```

Since the condition is the same, is there a **faster** way of doing this?

---

**Update 1:** After implementing kaya3's answer the program runs 0.05 - 0.2 seconds faster

Comment: You could try to use a dictionary in which you save as a key a pair that identifies the position on the chessboard and as a value X, O or an empty string. Later, you can cycle through the dictionary keys and check which of it has a certain value, for example empty string. Every time a player makes a move you will go to mark his move in the relative position in the dictionary

Comment: @ElidorDD Thanks for the comment! I have built my code around lists already, so implementing a dictionary might be difficult, but that's a good suggestion if I was starting from the beginning.

Comment: Let's say that dictionaries instead of lists would increase the efficiency of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the same thing for a series of different values, put them in a list, and then loop over it:

```py
sides = [(1, 0), (1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 1)]

for x, y in sides:
    if board[x][y] == ' ':
        return x, y
```

Comment: Or, to find all of the empty spaces, replace the for loop with a list comprehension: `empty = [(x,y) for x,y in sides if board[x][y] == ' ']`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know if this method is faster than using the elif statements?

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the comment! I only need one side though, so using list comprehension and then returning a value from the list might take longer than just using the elif statements.